# Android Service > Activity > Fragment with ViewPager

Tags: android, service, android-viewpager, orientation, fragment

First, I'd to state that I've been searching for a solution for this problem for three days now, that may means either I'm not asking the right question or not using a good approach. If any, please guide me in the right direction.

This is the scenario: I've an `Activity` and a bound `Service`. The `Service` holds some data and processes it as necessary while posting a persistent (ongoing) notification with some information. The `Activity` has three `Fragments` inside a `ViewPager` that displays the data processed by the `Service`.

The `Fragments` are a **List Fragment**, that shows the active data entries available, a **Details Fragment** that displays the details for each data and a **Parameters Fragment** where the user can modify how the data is processed.

[Service] <-> ([Activity] -> [ViewPager([List], [Details], [Parameters])])

Everything works just fine. My `Activity` binds to the `Service`, the `ViewPager` is created after and then the `Fragments` fetch information trough an `Interface`.

Here comes the fun part... Screen Rotation!

As the `Service` binds asynchronously, when the user rotates the screen the `Fragments` no longer have the data because the `Activity` is bounding the service while they're already present and not recreated thanks to the `ViewPager`.

I've been trying to figure this out but it seems that I don't have the knowledge to solve it. I've tried making static references to the fragments, setting them up before the service is rebound but I can't get a stable solution.

I'd be using `android:configChanges` in my manifest but there are different layouts for each orientation.

Again, if I'm using a bad approach, please, guide me!

Comment: You can try using a headless fragment to hold your data and bind your service to.  [Here](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/04/retaining-objects-across-config-changes.html) is a good tutorial.  It talks about using headless fragment with async task but the same could be applied to your case.  This is the recommended way of handling screen rotation.

Comment: Just did, as @Kuffs also suggested, and it works flawlessly! Can't thank you enough guys! :)

Comment: Anyway you can show your code, I am trying to figure out how to implement an interface to a fragment in a viewpager from an activity

Comment: @Lion789 Sorry for my late answer. If you still need it I can send you   the files via Dropbox. Let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Difficult to suggest when I don't know your code but thinking out loud....

Can you have a "worker fragment" that is never displayed (i.e headless) and has setRetainInstance(true) set so it does not lose any state you have set.

Your worker fragment would bind to the service instead of the activity and maintain a reference to it.

If you need to communicate with your Activity, you can do this with callbacks.

Your other fragments could communicate with the worker instead of the Activity.

This process would basically make the activity little more than a shell into which the rest of your components are hosted. Rotation would lose nothing because all data is held in the retained fragment.

Comment: That's perfect! Thank you so much! Wish I had thought about this a few days back.

Comment: Just tried this approach and it work like a charm! Thanks again! :)

Answer (score 0):

During the screen rotation process the activity is completely destroyed and use of android:congfigChange is discouraged. but what you can do is you can override saveInstanceState(bundle) method in which you can save the data present in your activity at the time it is destroyed by the system in response to the screen rotation. and later receive it as the system passes  the bundle to the activities onCreate(bundle) method or get it from the restoreInstanceState(Bundle) method.